# Consider $g\colon [0,1) \to S$ defined as $g(t)=(\cos2\pi t,\sin2\pi t)$, where $S=\{\,(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\,\}$.

Tags: general-topology

How can we show that image of $[0,1/4)$ under $g$ is not open in $S$?.

The topology considered on $[0,1)$ is the usual topology on $\mathbb R$.

I do not have any background for topology.So. please try to explain this geometrically,if possible.

Thank you!

Comment: What is $g$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @ArcticChar:Sorry,i forgot to type it.Now i edited the question.

Comment: A set is open if around every point in the set there exist an open ball such that every point in the open ball is in the set.  Try to construct an open ball around $g(0).$

Comment: @DougM:$g(0)$ is (1,0),and any open ball around (1,0) also fall outside the circle $S$ i.e, outside set $S$,Which means (1,0) do not lie in any open set of $S$.Is it so?

Comment: @PRADEEPSINGH that's the wrong idea here.  In particular, note that the image of $(0,1/4)$ under $g$ **is** open in $S$.  There is something special about the point $(1,0)$ here.

Comment: @PRADEEPSINGH what we really care about are points in the open ball that are in $S,$ but are not in the image of $g(t)$ over the desired interval.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the point $g(0) = (1,0)$ in the image of $g$.

For the image to be open, we would need to be able to take a neighborhood about the point $(1,0)$ that is small enough for it to include only other points (from the circle) that are in the image of $g$.  Note, however, that any open neighborhood around the point $(1,0)$ (that is, any circle around the point $(1,0)$) no matter how small it is, will include points from the circle *outside* of the image of $g$.

For this reason, the image of $g$ fails to be open in the circle.

---

Perhaps a more intuitive (and technically correct) idea is the following: any set that includes a part of its *boundary* will fail to be open.  Note, however, that a proof along these lines necessitates that we define what a "boundary" is.

Comment: :What is the form of open sets in S?

Comment: Any intersection of an open set in $\Bbb R^2$ with $S$.

Comment: @i was thinking that too :->)

Answer (score 0):

I guess $g$ is the exponential map. Simply because $A = \{ e^{i\theta} \mid \theta \in [0, \pi/2] \}$ is not open in $S^1$. For seeing this $g$ induce a homeomorphism $(0,1) \cong S^1 \backslash \{(1,0)\}$. So in particular, $g([0,1/4])$ is open in $S^1$ if and only if $[0,1/4]$ is open in $[0,1]$ but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The image $A$ of $[0,\tfrac14)$ under $g$ contains the point $g(0)=(1,0)$. To have an open set, all points o f$S$ "sufficiently close" to $(1,0)$ should also be in $A$. For example, the points $(\sqrt{1-h^2},-h)$ with $h$ small and positive are in $S$, are arbitrarily close to $(1,0)$, and are not in $A$ (because the $y$ component of point sin $A$ is always non-negative).